# Is there a way to bulk follow all usernames in a text list?

Tags: contacts, twitter

We've been collecting Twitter handles for contacts in our CRM systems for a while now. We're finally joining the 21st century and are deciding to start a Twitter account.

Is there a way (perhaps a handy program) for me to feed in a list of Twitter usernames and get my account to follow each of them?

Comment: Keep in mind there is a limit on how many accounts you can follow on Twitter, it currently stands at 2000 until you get more followers. You cannot follow more than 1000 people in one day

Answer (score 2):

Using [sferik/t](https://github.com/sferik/t):

```
t follow user1 user2 ...
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go, but since you answered I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get Ruby configured properly. Will mark as answered as soon as I've been able to test it.

Comment: Configured? `gem install t`...

Comment: Yeah, I followed the instructions, but my Ruby environments are giving me grief. On my Windows laptop, I can't install the Gem because of issues generating the native code. On my Ubuntu server, gem install hangs. On my SL server, there isn't a gem-compatible version of Ruby in the repo.

Comment: [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) can easily [install](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) the latest Ruby if that's needed.